# How can i implement keystore (certificate) soapui in C#?

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, certificate, ssl-certificate

I have sent a request and got a response from a web service using with SOAPUI

To do this, i added my client certificate to SOAPUI -> Preferences -> SSL Settings

And it worked successfully. (I am getting ssl handshake error if i dont add keystore and password)
[image]

My problem is that i couldn't implement this (soapui keystore ability) in C# code. Below is my code and the error i get.

[image]

Comment: Please don't post code as an image. It makes it difficult for people to copy and paste your code to try and run it or post answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i figured out the problem.

You should set the clientcertificate while creating the web service instance. 
 By the way, ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.SslCertificateAuthentication options are for only ignoring the servercertificate is valid or not.

```
        X509Certificate2 x509 = Utils.GetZBCertificate();
        ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.SslCertificateAuthentication = new System.ServiceModel.Security.X509ServiceCertificateAuthentication();
        ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.SslCertificateAuthentication.CertificateValidationMode = System.ServiceModel.Security.X509CertificateValidationMode.None;
        ChannelFactory.Credentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = x509;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can attach your certificates at the endpoint event.

Comment: Thank you!, this is the way i figured out the problem